# optimize insert max dates from 1 million row table

Tags: sql, db2, query-optimization

I need to get the max dates from a detail table which meets the following condition.
This transaction table reaches near 1 million rows.

Is there a better query than this?

```
insert into SCH1.maxDATES
     select a.ID, a.STATUS, max(detail.REGISTER_DATE) max_DATE
       from SCH1.User a
 inner join SCH1.Transaction detail on detail.ID = a.ID
      where a.STATUS = 3 and detail.REGISTER_DATE is not null
   group by a.ID, a.STATUS
```

Comment: Why are you inserting these values into a different table when you can simply select them as required?

Comment: Please omit the insert.It's an auxiliary table than takes this max time of a certain instant of time.

Comment: query is fine, what are your indexes?

Comment: you should probably move `detail.REGISTER_DATE is not null` up into the join clause (even though the optimizer is probably doing this for you); always do as much filtering in your join as you can.  Note that there are occasionally subtly different effects depending on where you stick them, but not for `INNER JOIN`s with `AND`s.

Answer (score 0):

Determine what the indexes are for that table and join on them if possible. Also being more specific, without limiting the data you want, is always better.

Here is a helpful site I commonly look at for optimization advice:
http://beginner-sql-tutorial.com/sql-query-tuning.htm